# Why I'm getting cors errors from non-www to www in WordPress rest API?

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, updating, wordpress-gutenberg

Every time I need to update a post or page that uses Gutenberg blocks, I get a message in the dashboard that says "Updating failed. Error message: The response is not a valid JSON response.".

I also get errors on Chrome and Firefox developer console saying:
Access to fetch at 'https://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_locale=user' from origin 'https://www.website.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-wp-nonce is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Could that be because the Rest URL has the 'www' on it? I can edit and save the posts normally on Safari, but not Chrome or Firefox.

Thanks

Comment: `www.domain.foo` and `domain.foo` are considered different domains, and you would require CORS to successfully crosspost

Comment: Had you solved this problem?

Answer (score -2):

When you save the post in Gutenberg the wordpress backend page expects from the server a JSON formatted response. So when you get this error it means something on the backend/PHP side doesn't work as it should. In my case I've used `print` or `echo` functions instead of

`return json_encode(array("with"=> "values"))`

in an post save action hook callback.

The second error is not related to the first one. The ajax call url should just be equal to the `window.location.origin` value